# Send Reply to email by Gmail API missing thread in replay

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-api, protractor, gmail-api

I am trying to replay to email hru gmail api as described: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

I am successfully replaying to email however my goal is to have replay with original email thread like you would do thru gmail UI.
It is replaying even changing email subject to have "Re:" prefix however it is not threading original email for some reason.
Any help apprepiate.

**Google documentation says this:**

If you're trying to send a reply and want the email to thread, make sure that:

1. The **Subject headers** match
2. The **References** and **In-Reply-To** headers follow the RFC 2822 standard.

I have taken **references**, **subject**, **inReplyTo** and **threadId** variables from original message i am replaying to by executing query thru  **gmail.users.messages.get**.

I also have tried to creade draft but results are the same (draft without original email thread content).

```
  public async send() {
    const from = 'aaaaaaa@bbbbbb.co';
    const to = 'aaa.bbbb@gmail.com';
    const subject = 'test 01';
    const text = 'bbbbbbbbbbb';
    const inReplyTo='<CAHmEgS2VvD8i-B-PrHRXA0Egwed4RcW7f3wNbMYiCx5YqYhYsw@mail.gmail.com>';
    const references='<CAHmEgS2VvD8i-B-PrHRXA0Egwed4RcW7f3wNbMYiCx5YqYhYsw@mail.gmail.com>';
    const threadId = '17c26a0c9045c813';

    const buildMessage = () => new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      const message  = new MailComposer({
          from: from,
          to: to,
          subject: subject,
          text: text,
          textEncoding: 'base64',
          headers: {
            'In-Reply-To': inReplyTo,
            'References': references,
          }
      })

      message.compile().build((err, msg) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err)
        } 
      
        const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(msg)
          .toString('base64')
          .replace(/\+/g, '-')
          .replace(/\//g, '_')
          .replace(/=+$/, '')

        resolve(encodedMessage)
      })
  })

  const encodedMessage = await buildMessage()

    const auth = await this.authorize();
    const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return gmail.users.messages.send(
        {
          userId: 'me',
          requestBody: {
            raw: encodedMessage,
            threadId: threadId
          }
        },
        (err: any, res: any) => {
          if (err) reject(err);
          resolve(res);
          const messages = res.data.messages;
          if (messages.length) {
            messages.forEach((message: { id: any; threadId: any; }) => {
              console.log(`${message.id}_${message.threadId}`);
            });
          } else {
            console.error('No messages found.');
          }
          
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you sending an email to a non Workspace/Gmail account by chance?

Comment: Hi @RafaGuillermo I send an email to another Gmail account

Comment: Can you get the non-threading to replicate if you use the [Try this API feature](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send)?

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION !

```
const threadId = originalMessage.threadId;

    const headers = originalMessage.payload.headers;
    const from = headers.find((header) => header.name === 'From').value;
    const to = headers.find((header) => header.name === 'To').value;
    const inReplyTo = headers.find(
        (header) => header.name === 'Message-ID'
    ).value;
    const subject = headers.find(
        (header) => header.name === 'Subject'
    ).value;

    const body = 'ALLLLLEZZZZ';

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const utf8Subject = `=?utf-8?B?${Buffer.from(subject).toString(
        'base64'
    )}?=`;
    const messageParts = [
        'From: ' + to,
        'To: ' + from,
        'In-Reply-To: ' + inReplyTo,
        'References: ' + inReplyTo,
        'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        'Subject: ' + utf8Subject,
        '',
        '' + body,
    ];

    // on join tous ces bouts de phrases
    const message = messageParts.join('\r\n');

    // The body needs to be base64url encoded.
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(message)
        .toString('base64')
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')
        .replace(/\//g, '_')
        .replace(/=+$/, '');

    const res = await m.gmail.users.messages.send({
        userId: 'me',
        requestBody: {
            raw: encodedMessage,
            threadId: threadId,
        },
    });
    console.log('Message send');
    console.log(res.data);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).